# CollectionView using DataTemplate is not updating ReactiveContentView BindingContext or ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I'm using ReactiveUI and trying to get a CollectionView to use a ReactiveContentPage as it's item template in code behind.  This works okay until the ReactiveContentView is nested under another Element.

The problem I have is that after scrolling the collection view, the items get duplicated.  After debugging, it would seem that the ReactiveContentView's BindingContext or ViewModel aren't updated.

The samples below have been simplified to highlight the issue:

This doesn't work:

```
    public partial class SampleCollectionPage : ReactiveContentPage<SampleCollectionViewModel>
    {
        private void Build()
        {
            Content = new CollectionView
            {
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    return new ContentView
                    {
                        Content = new ReactiveContentView<CollectionItemViewModel>
                        {
                            Content = new StackLayout
                            {
                                Children =
                                {
                                    new Label()
                                        .Bind(Label.TextProperty, nameof(CollectionItemViewModel.Title)),

                                    new Label()
                                        .Bind(Label.TextProperty, nameof(CollectionItemViewModel.Description)),

                                    new Label()
                                        .Bind(Label.TextProperty, nameof(CollectionItemViewModel.SomeTime)),
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }),
            }
            .Bind(CollectionView.ItemsSourceProperty, path: nameof(SampleCollectionViewModel.Items));
        }
    }
```

This works:

```
    public partial class SampleCollectionPage : ReactiveContentPage<SampleCollectionViewModel>
    {
        private void Build()
        {
            Content = new CollectionView
            {
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    return new ReactiveContentView<CollectionItemViewModel>
                    {
                        Content = new StackLayout
                        {
                            Children =
                            {
                                new Label()
                                    .Bind(Label.TextProperty, nameof(CollectionItemViewModel.Title)),

                                new Label()
                                    .Bind(Label.TextProperty, nameof(CollectionItemViewModel.Description)),

                                new Label()
                                    .Bind(Label.TextProperty, nameof(CollectionItemViewModel.SomeTime)),
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }),
            }
            .Bind(CollectionView.ItemsSourceProperty, path: nameof(SampleCollectionViewModel.Items));
        }
    }
```

The only difference being that the working version doesn't put the ReactiveContentView in a ContentView.  I'm not sure if I'm missing something or whether this is an bug in Xamarin Forms or ReactiveUI?

(edited to add actual problem: doh)

Comment: BindingContext isn't used by rxui code behind binding. Instead we get you the use the ViewModel property.

Comment: Looking at [github](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/371b7fc117c44636f865cc5c5b5d09220d7acec0/src/ReactiveUI.XamForms/ReactiveContentView.cs) the binding context is set to the view model and vice versa.  When testing neither is updated.  (nb the binds above were for simplicity, in reals they are done using rxui methods)